# How can I construct procedures for usage in racket lisp engines?

Tags: multithreading, lisp, racket

I would like to use racket lisp engines which allow execution of a procedure that can be interrupted by a timer timeout. I'm not sure how to construct a procedure that engine will accept because I can't find examples online. [At the engine documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/engine.html) it lists input proc having the following contract:

```
(engine proc) → engine?
  proc : ((any/c . -> . void?) . -> . any/c)
```

I'm just learning typed racket annotation semantics and this is above my head at the moment. Can someone help provide some concrete examples of valid procedures that can be use in a racket engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played a little around with it. Here is what I did:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/engine)

(define (test-engine allow-interrupt)
  (let loop ((n 1))
    (allow-interrupt #f)
    (displayln (list 'step n))
    (allow-interrupt #t)
    (sleep 1)
    (loop (add1 n))))

(define tee (engine test-engine))
(engine-run 2000 tee)
```

I noticed that it might break in the middle of a `displayln` so to make `displayln` atomic I made use of the supplied procedure that makes delays the interruption during atomic operations. Without it it will print out the rest in the next `(engine-run 2000 tee)` instead of finishing it before it returns.

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for! Question, how are you treating the provided boolean as a procedure? It looks like you're invoking the variable as a set! function

Comment: @durandaltheta According to the documentation "The argument to proc is a procedure that takes a boolean". It could never be a boolean itself since changing it would change a local binding and not affect anything outside. With a procedure it can alter its environment, which is hidden from us. It's basically message passing so it can be seen as OO.

Comment: Aha, I misread that documentation, which was the core source of my confusion. Now it all makes sense, thanks!